# Peewee disabling automatic cast

Tags: python, python-3.x, peewee

When trying to insert in database using peewee, if the datatype does not match peewee tries to cast it and if not possible simply inserts the default value for that particular field.

```
Schema:
Table Users:
          Id (int)
          Username(int)
          Email(varchar(30))
```

Trying to insert

```
Users(1, ‘abc’, ‘abc@mail.com’)
```

The username datatype being int but when trying to insert string, it inserts the default value of integer which is 0.

How to stop peewee from performing this automatic casting and force it to through exception?

Comment: Without code and a specific example it's very difficult to even attempt to help.

Comment: I tried giving an example, check if now you can help.

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: mySQL is the database being used here

Comment: Your example is only pseudocode. You need to provide actual python code (e.g. `User` class, and your DB schema `show create table user`)